# Communication between python script server and web server using requests

Tags: javascript, python, html

I want to translate a program made with arduino to do the same on a raspberry pi. In arduino I have got a web page with some javascript code as a web server to send get request to the program code and tell it what I want to do (an example, open a solenoid valve). For doing it, I have to make the code understands the requests sent by the javascript code from the html web page.

This is a part of the javascript code on the web page for sending requests;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function manual(X){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open("GET", "/arduino/" + X + "&" + Math.random(), true);
request.send(null);
}
</script>
```

And this is the part on the arduino program that received the requests;

```
YunClient client = server.accept();  // try to get client

if (client) {  // got client?
    String req = client.readString();
    req.trim();

            Console.println(req);
```

So I want to do the same with a python script and the same web page I used in arduino. I suppose I have to change this part;

```
request.open("GET", "/arduino/" + X + "&" + Math.random(), true);
```

For this one;

```
request.open("GET", "http://localhost:PORT" + X + "&" + Math.random(), true);
```

Obviously putting the port used by the python script to "listen" for incoming requests.

The fact is, I don't know exactly how to do it. I have tried with some socket server code like this;

```
 import socket
import sys

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name, meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8888 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

s.close()
```

But nothing happend. Maybe it could be something like this;

```
if request.method == 'GET' and 'q' in request.GET:
    q = request.GET.get('q', None)
    if q is not None:
```

Thats a code found on the internet, in fact appears in a question done on this forum.

I hope this explanation was better than before. The fact is I want to try to catch the requests from the web server side and process them with the python script as I did with the arduino code. The python script is not still written because I have to resolve this point. The rest of the code is easy to translate to python.

Comment: if you need HTML server then use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` (Python2)

Comment: you have to put `/` after port `PORT/" + X`

Comment: your socket server doesn't receive data from client - ie. `conn.recv(1024)`. Besides it is not HTML server so it doesn't have `request.method` and `request.GET` so better use `SimpleHTTPServer` if you really need HTML server (with static pages). Or `Flask` if you need dynamic generated pages.